# JSON String parsing each character as an object

Tags: json

I have a JSON file that contains what I believe to be a correct JSON string:

```
{"title": "exampleTitle", "tipTitle": "exampleTipTitle", "tip": "exampleTip"}
```

I'm trying to parse said file and take out the 3 values then store them in variables, however currently, it parses each individual character as a separate object, therefore:

```
JSONobj[1] =  "
```

and so on. Assuming that currentLocation = the directory location of the json file.

**Code**

```
var jsonLocation = currentLocation + "json.txt";
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", jsonLocation, false);
request.send(null);
var returnValue = request.responseText;
var JSONobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(returnValue));
var headerTitle = JSONobj[0];
```

A few clarifications,  the stringify is in because it was throwing an unexpected token error. I've tried changing the file tile to .json instead but that also makes no difference. "It also gives off a XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated" but I'm not particularly sure how to solve that issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note: Avoid passing `false` as the third argument to `open`. Instead, embrace the asynchronous nature of web programming.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> var returnValue = request.responseText;
> ```

Here `returnValue` is a string of JSON.

```
"{\"title\": \"exampleTitle\", \"tipTitle\": \"exampleTipTitle\", \"tip\": \"exampleTip\"}
```

> ```
> var JSONobj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(returnValue));
> ```

Here you convert the string of JSON to JSON. So you have a JSON string representing a string, and that string is a representation of a data structure in JSON.

```
"\"{\\"title\\": \\"exampleTitle\\", \\"tipTitle\\": \\"exampleTipTitle\\", \\"tip\\": \\"exampleTip\\"}"
```

Then you parse it and convert it back to the original string of JSON.

```
"{\"title\": \"exampleTitle\", \"tipTitle\": \"exampleTipTitle\", \"tip\": \"exampleTip\"}
```

So you end up back where you start.

Just don't use `JSON.stringify` here, and you'll convert your JSON to a JavaScript object:

```
var javascript_object = JSON.parse(returnValue);
```

---

Then you have an object, but it doesn't have a `0` property so it doesn't make sense to access it with `javascript_object[0]`.  The properties have names, such as `javascript_object.title`.

Comment: I see, this returned object Object but I can see that my problem was more that I was trying to index something that wasn't actually an array. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON doesn't describe an array, so indexing into it with an index like `0` doesn't make sense. Your JSON describes an *object*, which will have properties with the names `title`, `tipTitle`, and `tip`.

Additionally, you're overdoing your parsing: You just want to *parse*, not stringify (which is the opposite of parsing):

```
var JSONobj = JSON.parse(returnValue);
```

So:

```
var JSONobj = JSON.parse(returnValue);
var headerTitle = JSONobj.title;
console.log(headerTitle); // "exampleTitle"
```

---

Side note: By the time you've assigned it to the variable you've called `JSONobj`, it isn't JSON anymore, it's just a normal JavaScript object, so that name is a bit misleading. If you're writing source code, and you're not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON anymore. :-)